# Svelte 3: Could not import modules when unit testing

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs, svelte, svelte-3

I'm trying to test a Svelte component with Jest. This component works fine in the browser, but unit test fails with importing modules.

For example, when running Jest, `import uuid from 'uuid'` compiled as `const { default: uuid } = require("uuid");`, and calling `uuid.v4()` causes `TypeError: Cannot read property 'v4' of undefined`. When I use `import * as uuid from 'uuid'` or `const uuid = require('uuid')`, Jest unit test passes, but it doesn't work in the browser.

How can I deal with this issue? Any information would greatly help. Thank you.

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "svelte-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "rollup -c",
    "dev": "rollup -c -w",
    "start": "firebase serve --only hosting"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@rollup/plugin-json": "^4.0.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.1.1",
    "@testing-library/svelte": "^1.11.0",
    "bulma": "^0.8.0",
    "eslint": "^6.7.0",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^14.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.18.2",
    "eslint-plugin-jest": "^23.0.4",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^10.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^4.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "^4.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-svelte3": "^2.7.3",
    "jest-transform-svelte": "^2.1.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.13.1",
    "rollup": "^1.12.0",
    "rollup-jest": "0.0.2",
    "rollup-plugin-commonjs": "^10.0.0",
    "rollup-plugin-livereload": "^1.0.0",
    "rollup-plugin-node-builtins": "^2.1.2",
    "rollup-plugin-node-globals": "^1.4.0",
    "rollup-plugin-node-resolve": "^5.2.0",
    "rollup-plugin-svelte": "^5.0.3",
    "rollup-plugin-terser": "^5.1.2",
    "sirv-cli": "^0.4.5",
    "svelma": "^0.3.2",
    "svelte": "^3.18.2",
    "svelte-preprocess": "^3.4.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase": "^7.8.2"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

rollup.config.js

```
import json from '@rollup/plugin-json'
import commonjs from 'rollup-plugin-commonjs'
import builtins from 'rollup-plugin-node-builtins'
import globals from 'rollup-plugin-node-globals'
import livereload from 'rollup-plugin-livereload'
import resolve from 'rollup-plugin-node-resolve'
import svelte from 'rollup-plugin-svelte'
import { terser } from 'rollup-plugin-terser'
import preprocess from 'svelte-preprocess'

const production = !process.env.ROLLUP_WATCH

export default {
  input: 'src/main.js',
  output: {
    sourcemap: true,
    format: 'iife',
    name: 'app',
    file: 'public/build/bundle.js',
  },
  plugins: [
    // https://github.com/rollup/plugins/tree/master/packages/json
    json(),

    svelte({
      // enable run-time checks when not in production
      dev: !production,
      // we'll extract any component CSS out into
      // a separate file — better for performance
      css: css => {
        css.write('public/build/bundle.css')
      },
      preprocess: preprocess(),
    }),

    // If you have external dependencies installed from
    // npm, you'll most likely need these plugins. In
    // some cases you'll need additional configuration —
    // consult the documentation for details:
    // https://github.com/rollup/rollup-plugin-commonjs
    resolve({
      browser: true,
      dedupe: importee => importee === 'svelte' || importee.startsWith('svelte/'),
    }),
    commonjs(),
    globals(),
    builtins(),

    // In dev mode, call `npm run start` once
    // the bundle has been generated
    !production && serve(),

    // Watch the `public` directory and refresh the
    // browser on changes when not in production
    !production && livereload('public'),

    // If we're building for production (npm run build
    // instead of npm run dev), minify
    production && terser(),
  ],
  watch: {
    clearScreen: false,
  },
}

function serve () {
  let started = false

  return {
    writeBundle () {
      if (!started) {
        started = true

        require('child_process').spawn('npm', ['run', 'start'], {
          stdio: ['ignore', 'inherit', 'inherit'],
          shell: true,
        })
      }
    },
  }
}
```

jest.config.js

```
const sveltePreprocess = require('svelte-preprocess')

module.exports = {
  displayName: { name: 'web', color: 'magentaBright' },
  moduleFileExtensions: [
    'js',
    'json',
    'svelte',
  ],
  preset: 'rollup-jest',
  transform: {
    '\\.js$': 'rollup-jest',
    '\\.svelte$': ['jest-transform-svelte', { preprocess: sveltePreprocess(), debug: true }],
  },
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect'],
}
```

Comment: I am having the same issue. I've not found a way past this as yet

Answer (score 1):

**It worked for me.**

The issue seems like jest unable to resolve uuid while building the code at runtime. 
Which is quite obvious because **by default jest ignore node_modules packages**.

I faced similar issues and resolved it. The approach is by configuration inform JEST  that it has to include node_modules packages as well. In my project i used rollup-plugin-babel. 
This is the babel plugin configuration

```
...
...
babel({
    extensions: [ '.js', '.mjs', '.html', '.svelte' ],
    runtimeHelpers: true,
    exclude: [ 'node_modules/@babel/**', 'node_modules/core-js/**' ],
    presets: [
      [
        '@babel/preset-env',
        {
          targets: '> 0.25%, not dead',
          useBuiltIns: 'usage',
          corejs: 3 
        }
      ]
    ]
  })
```

And I've added babel-jest for transforming the jest.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  preset: 'jest-puppeteer', //ignore the preset part, I used for puppeteer
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.js?$': require.resolve('babel-jest'),
    "^.+\\.ts?$": "ts-jest" // this part is only required if you have typescript project
  }
};
```

DO Not forget to install this packages like babel-jest, rollup-plugin-babel before using it.

Comment: I really appreciate that you took the time to give a detailed explanation. I don't want to add more compilers for now, but your way is really useful for who already using Babel. Maybe I'll have to adopt your way in the future. Thank you!

Comment: @astanet if you find this answer helpful, accept and upvote it, so that people facing similar issue will be benefited.

Answer (score 0):

I have been facing this same issue and have a work around by mocking the module in the test file and giving it a default key.

```
jest.mock('uuid', () => ({
  default: {
    v4: jest.fn(),
  },
}))
```

Another way that seems to work is to destructure the import in the component file.

```
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid'
```

Comment: Sadly, your workaround doesn't work for me, but I really glad that you took time for this issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Self answer:

Finally, I wrote a little preprocessor to replace `import foo from 'foo'` -> `import * as foo from 'foo'`

svelteJestPreprocessor.js

```
const svelteJestPreprocessor = () => ({
  // replace `import foo from 'foo'` -> `import * as foo from 'foo'`
  script: ({ content }) => ({
    // process each line of code
    code: content.split('\n').map(line =>
      // pass: no import, import with {}, import svelte component
      (!line.match(/\s*import/)) || (line.match(/{/)) || (line.match(/\.svelte/)) ? line
        : line.replace(/import/, 'import * as'),
    ).join('\n'),
  }),
})

module.exports = svelteJestPreprocessor
```

jest.config.js

```
const svelteJestPreprocessor = require('./svelteJestPreprocessor')
const sveltePreprocess = require('svelte-preprocess')

module.exports = {
  moduleFileExtensions: [
    'js',
    'json',
    'svelte',
  ],
  preset: 'rollup-jest',
  transform: {
    '\\.js$': 'rollup-jest',
    '\\.svelte$': ['jest-transform-svelte', {
      preprocess: [
        svelteJestPreprocessor(),
        sveltePreprocess(),
      ],
    }],
  },
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect'],
}
```

This is an unwanted workaround, but it works for now.